# puppeteer css for local html is not showing up

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to generate a pdf using local html but the css isn't showing up

```
 (async () => {
 var html = '<div style="width:500px; height:500px;background:blue">test</div>'
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.setContent(html)
 await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

 await browser.close();
 })();
```

How can I get the css to work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `printBackground: true` to your `page.pdf` call

`await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4', printBackground: true});`

The problem wasn't with CSS, thee CSS is showed but when you print a page the backgrounds are removed. Try adding `color:red;` to your CSS and you'll see that the CSS work.

Comment: `await is undefined`

Comment: Sorry @hmaxx I made a big mistake, I've just fixed my answer and I've tested it locally with a new repo 